# How do I put HTML photos in a different div? PHP I think?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a Wordpress page in the making, and basically I have a title column and a text column.

The issue is that I am using the wordpress text editor, and its putting all of my content into the text column but I want a couple of photos and captions for those photos to go into the title column so that the readers read and theres pictures alongside. I was successful with using position:absolute, except that the photos were no longer responsive to zooming in and out on the webpages.

How can I keep the written content in the text column, and the pictures in the title column and have them still be responsive to zoom that they stay within the title-column with zooming in/out?

(I put the "<" in (<) on purpose)

(<)a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/18.jpg">
(<)img class="size-medium wp-image-146 alignleft"; 
(<)src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/18.jpg" alt="Age 18" width="175" height="400" />

(<)div id=caption18>Me around age 18(<)/ div>

```
/* Two Column Title Layout */
div.title-column {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

div.text-column {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}
```

```
<article class="post page">

    <!-- column-container -->
    <div class="column-container clearfix">

        <!-- title-column -->
        <div class="title-column">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div><!-- /title-column -->

        <!-- text-column -->
        <div class="text-column">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- /text-column -->

    </div><!-- /column-container -->


</article>

<?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you are trying to do something like this while retaining the scalability of the image(s)? Note that I had to adjust some of your brackets. I also changed the width of the image to "auto" and the height to "0". This should retain the scalability of the image, but I have not tested it.

```
    <!-- title-column -->
    <div class="title-column">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/18.jpg">
           <img class="size-medium wp-image-146 alignleft" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/18.jpg" alt="Age 18" width="auto" height="0">
        </a>
    </div><!-- /title-column -->
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that does work, But, just curious, do you know if there is a way to use php to grab the html photo here with some conditional logic? It would be great if I didnt have to put the photo in the php file since I use the file for multiple pages. Although I guess I could make a separate page template...

Comment: You are welcome! Please vote up my answer if it helped. 
I think you are looking for something like this, which will only print the HTML for the image if on the desired page:
`<?php 
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'page_name.php') {
    echo '__PUT_YOUR_HTML_HERE__';
}
?>`

Comment: Thanks! Im still new so an upvote wont show unfortunately, but I did press the arrow up button.